# Add Zendesk chat to Salesforce Community

Tags: community, chat

Is it possible to add an external chat system to a Salesforce community? We have a Zendesk chat system that we use on our website, and I've been asked if it's possible to add that chat system into our customer community. Googling only gives me hits on adding Salesforce chat (which we don't have access to and don't want to pay for) to a community or about some sort of integration between Zendesk and Salesforce, but that's not exactly what I'm after.

I simply want a way to embed the Zendesk chat agent on the Salesforce community. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

To provide you one-liner "Yes" you can.

This link provides you a high-level; not detail level what you are interested.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.hvs_setup_bot_experience_cloud.htm&type=5

I have scanned through Zendesk unable to find a document similar to the Genesys product documentation.

https://help.mypurecloud.com/articles/about-genesys-cloud-for-salesforce/

Please try using chatbot for better results.

Thanks,
Krishna